# Spring, drop a DataSource for testing purpose?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am writing tests for my Spring Batch flow. I need to assert the behaviour of my app in edge cases where it cant establish the datasource at certain points.

I have a separate config file that creates H2 in memory databases that I run my tests on, which persist between tests. Is there a way of blocking a test from using these DataSource Beans where it wont cause issues in my tests that need them, because I'll need to simulate the connection dropping partway through a flow.

Cheers.

Comment: You can use mock objects for testing.